# How to make QuerySet JSON serializable?

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a problem with creating a new object in my Rest Framework.

As much I as understand, when I tried to overwrite item's field so it could have all the items that are in my database. I thought, that this would work, and it showed me the working page and I could choose an item. But when I tried to post it to create a new object, it said "Object of type 'Item' is not JSON serializable"

I was trying to figure it out, how to convert `Item.objects.all()` into JSON data. But nothing helped me. I understand, that this isn't really hard to do, but I can't figure it out on my own.

So I ask for your help, how to solve this problem?

Here's my serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from items.models import OrderItem, Item

class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=Item.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem 
        fields = ('item', 'size', 'quantity', 'id')
```

Comment: This is not a choice field, but a relation. There are several options here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: The error seems you've done something wrong with the views. Please show your views.py?

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from items.models import OrderItem, Item

class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem 
        fields = ('item', 'size', 'quantity', 'id')

    def get_item (self, obj):
        # in value list name all fields u want or empty for defaults 
        return Item.objects.all().values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

...
and inside the create method (post in Serializer)
...

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        req = self.context.get('request')
        items = req.data.get('item')
        if items:
            [OrderItem.item.add(
                oneitem) for oneitem in items]
```